# Issue Using set_prop_cycle to style fig in matplotlib - Colors not being impelemented

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm creating a stacked bar chart, and style it with the set_prop_cycle, because with 15 different elements, using a regular set style ended up with repeated colors. For instance, winter and hurricane are the same colors now, which I want to avoid.

I know there is also a way to create a loop instead of the library, but am not sure how.

This is my current code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.cm as mplcm
from cycler import cycler


yearly_tcount = pd.read_pickle('yearly_tcount.pkl')
yearly_tcount=yearly_tcount.reset_index()
yearly_tcount = yearly_tcount.drop(labels = [0, 1], axis=0 )


yearly_tcount.columns = ['Start_year', 'Disaster_Type','Event_Count']


types = ['Flood', 'Drought', 'Earthquake', 'Hurricane', 'Storm', 'Tornado',
       'Typhoon', 'Fire', 'Ice']


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

cy = cycler('color', [
    '#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a',
    '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94',
    '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f'
    ])


yearly_tcount.pivot(index='Start_year', columns = 'Disaster_Type', values='Event_Count' ).plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, zorder=3,)
ax.legend(ncol=3, edgecolor='w')
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right', 'left']]
ax.tick_params(axis='both', left=False, bottom=False)

ax.set_prop_cycle(cy)

ax.grid(axis='y', dashes=(8,3), color='grey', alpha=0.3)

fig.savefig('Change_in_Type_of_Winter_Weather_Events')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cycler is a repetition of 10 colors, if you set an arbitrary number of colors in the color map, it will be classified by those colors. I use plotly for the data so you can replace it with your own data.

```
import plotly.express as px
data = px.data.gapminder()

europe = data[data.continent == 'Europe']
europe_top15 = europe.groupby('country')['pop'].last().sort_values(ascending=False).head(15)
euro = europe_top15.index.tolist()

df = europe[europe['country'].isin(euro)]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

colors = ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a',
          '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94',
          '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f'
         ]
cmap = ListedColormap(colors, name="custom")

df.pivot(index='year', columns = 'country', values='pop' ).plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, zorder=3, cmap=cmap)
ax.legend(ncol=3, edgecolor='w')
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right', 'left']]
ax.tick_params(axis='both', left=False, bottom=False)

ax.grid(axis='y', dashes=(8,3), color='grey', alpha=0.3)

fig.savefig('Change_in_Type_of_Winter_Weather_Events')
```

[image]